# Почему не отображается сразу DateTimePicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, плагин, datetime, datepicker

Почему не отображается сразу календарь в плагине *datetimepicker*?
[Сайт плагина](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker), вариант `Inline DateTimePicker` отображается сразу, у меня на сайте пока не нажмешь на элементы навигации календаря выводит это:

[image: пустой календарь]

Вот как я подключаю *datetimepicker*:

```
<script src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/sychhrp52w3lbrb/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      format:'d.m.Y H:i',
      inline: true,
      scrollMonth: false,
      theme:'dark'
    });
    $('.xdsoft_today_button').trigger('tap');
  });
</script>
```

Мой сайт:
http://vyacheslavs-dynamite-site-b81f5b.webflow.io/serv

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос, не думаю что кому-то охота шариться по вашему сайту в поисках конкретного неработающего куска

Answer (score 1):

У вас не задано значение `input`, к которому аттачится datepicker.

Исправьте `<input id="datetimepicker" value="18.01.2017 00:27" type="text" />`

Comment: Там первый календарь с динамической датой, и там нет значения value

Comment: подключил версию с сайта все работает

Answer (score 0):

Подключил версию с сайта 2.4, против той что на гитхабе 1.3 и все заработало.